# Turtles dying according to slider

Tags: slider, netlogo

I want to make a certain number of turtles (controlled by a slider) die every year. So far I got this, it is probably very straightforward but I can't seem to make it work. 
Thanks a lot!

```
to hunting

let huntedturtles (count turtles = hunted-turtles) ; Hunted-turtles is the slider. 

      if ticks mod 365 = 0 

  [ask huntedturtles [die]]

  set hunted hunted + hunted-monkeys 

end
```

Answer (score 3):

You're getting an error like `ERROR: ASK expected this input to be an agent or agentset, but got a TRUE/FALSE instead`, correct?

`count turtles = hunted-turtles` is checking whether or not the total number of turtles is equal to `hunted-turtles`. I don't think that's what you want. Instead, you probably want something like

```
let huntedturtles n-of hunted-turtles turtles
```

That's going to randomly choose `hunted-turtles` turtles.

Side note: `huntedturtles` and `hunted-turtles` are easily confusable variable names. Consider making the slider `num-hunted-turtles` or something similar, and the set of hunted turtles themselves `hunted-turtles`.

Comment: Thanks! It still doesn't work. Turtles die at the first tick and then I get this message: `Requested 11 random agents from a set of only 7 agents. error while turtle 48 running N-OF.` Even though there are still enough turtles to choose from. 
Is there a way of having "huntedturtles" be the exact number as the slider?  Hope you can help with this. Code looks now like this. 
  
    `to hunting  
  let huntedturtles n-of hunting-rate turtles
  
  if ticks mod 365 = 0
   [
   output-print "hunted"
    ;set hunted hunted + hunting-rate 
    ask huntedturtles [die]]
  end`

Comment: I take it your slider is set to 11? You're getting that error because after it kills off the 11 turtles in the first tick, there aren't enough turtles left in the second tick to choose 11 of them! How you fix that depends on how you want your model to behave. Try a few things out. If you still get stuck, open a new question here.